# mRemote and RoyalTS both are not able to RDP connect me to a Windows Server 2008 system?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, windows-terminal-services

I am completely stuck on this one.   If I start a RDP session independently of these 2 programs everything works fine.   My RDP session connects, I click "OK" to accept the "Notice To Users" security message and then it shows me the login screen where I enter my password manually.

Now, if I try to use either mRemote or RoyalTS  to create this connection, I get the same behavior except that I get a "The user name or password is incorrect."  message.   Now, I know this cannot be true since I can manually connect with RDP.

So, what is the problem with these 2 pieces of software that prevents me from logging in?   I have no problems with connecting to Windows XP systems with these programs.

Additionally, I wish I knew how to get one of these programs to automatically click the "OK" button on the "Notice To Users" message while automatically attempting to log me in  as part of the login process.  Can they do that?

Comment: Does the windows 2008 server only allow connections via NLA?

Comment: That seems to be the case I suppose.  What else do you know about that?  Does mRemote not work with NLA?

Comment: I also tried mRemoteNG  and it doesn't work either.

Comment: I have no experience with mRemote.  I just know that a lot of alternate RDP clients break when only NLA is allowed.

Comment: @djangofan - Any update on this?

Comment: the mRemoteNG, that supposedly works with NLA, also didn't work for me.  i had to give up on it.  i assume it has something to do with the NLA "local" policy though, which i dont have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you requiring NLA on the server box? If so, then that's likely the culprit.

Comment: Cripes - I don't know how I missed all the comments above about NLA. Anyway, if that's the answer, one of you guys should create a real answer so you can get the points.